# Why does the Treasury Stock Method assume that the company in question is the one who gets the proceeds of the exercised options?

Tags: stock-analysis, accounting

Reading about [TSM](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/treasurystockmethod.asp) for counting diluted shares outstanding and confused about how things are being worded.

I think I understand the procedure of how to do the calculations to get to the TSM diluted shares, but the method seems to assume that the company in question is the only entity that can create options contracts and so would be the only one to collect the proceeds of all options exercised in order to buy back shares.

Is this not wrong? Or is this a hypothetical way to think about the method and there is actually some other underlying logic for why TSM still makes sense even though the company is not the only one creating options contract? If so, could someone explain that reasoning in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key thing that you are missing here is that only options written by the company itself can result in the creation of new shares and therefore be dilutative.

For options created by external entities such as Investment Banks or Brokers the shares delivered when the option is exercised are delivered from the already existing stock of shares on the market. This means that at exercise of these options one party (the seller of a call or buyer of a put) must either use shares that they had already bought from the company or buy them on the market to fulfil the exercise. Since in both cases these shares already exist they are not increasing the number of outstanding shares so they don't change the quantity of shares.

Only the company itself can create new shares in itself therefore only options written by the company itself will result in dilution.

Comment: I get that only the company can create new shares. My confusion is: Does the TMS count *all options in existence* (created by the company as well as others) as the total number of options that can create new shares (eg. does TMS say "*assume, hypothetically*, that all ITM options in existence create new shares, what would the dilution be?") **OR** is it based on the options contracts *that the company itself has actually created* (if so, where in the financial statements can this be found?).

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter in the business when we say an option is "written" we mean that it is created. With that in mind my answer tells you that TMS can only count the dilutative options issued by the company and *not* options created on outstanding shares as they won't increase the number of shares.

Answer (score 2):

The key to the answer is in the first sentence of that article:

> The treasury stock method is an approach that companies use to compute the number of new shares that can potentially be created by unexercised in-the-money warrants and options.

Yes, anybody could create an option contact using the company's stock, but they would not be able to create new shares. If someone else's call option contact expires in the money, the seller of the contract would have to purchase an existing share of the stock from the market, which would not increase dilution of outstanding shares..

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter I don't understand your question.

Comment: "Anybody could create an option contact using the company's stock, but they would not be able to create new shares". So does the TSM assume that all existing unexercised ITM options on the market belong to the company (as a sort of theoretical question) or does TSM refer only the unexercised options contracts that the company is actually on the hook for fulfilling (if so where is that in financial statements)?